# How would I fix the Syntax error insert '}' to complete block

Tags: java, neo4j, user-defined-functions

I'm keep getting an error with my code. I'm creating a simple user-defined function for Neo4j. Can anyone help me with this? No matter what I try I get the following error:

> Syntax Error: Insert "}" to complete block.

When I insert `}` it gives me an error saying that my code is "unreachable" and when I add a bracket to make it reachable it takes me back to the first error and it just loops.

Here is my code:

```
public class Join {
  static Cipher cipher;
  @UserFunction
  @Description("example.DES ,, Decryption of any input values.")
  public byte[] DES(@Name("set1") List < String > strings1) {
    for (int i = 0; i < strings1.size(); i++) {
      String dot;
      dot = strings1.get(i);
      KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
      keyGenerator.init(128);
      SecretKey secretKey = keyGenerator.generateKey();
      cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
      String encryptedText = encrypt(dot, secretKey);
      System.out.println("Encrypted Text After Encryption: " + encryptedText);
    }
    public static String encrypt(String dot, SecretKey secretKey)
    throws Exception {
      byte[] plainTextByte = dot.getBytes();
      cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
      byte[] encryptedByte = cipher.doFinal(plainTextByte);
      Base64.Encoder encoder = Base64.getEncoder();
      String encryptedText = encoder.encodeToString(encryptedByte);
      return encryptedText;
    }
  }
```

Comment: THe posted code has 4 opening parenthesis `{` but only 3 closing ones `}`. The error message is pretty helpful and tells you everything: You are missing a closing parenthesis.

Comment: Currently your `encrypt` method is inside your `DES` method. Perhaps you just need to add a `}` after the `for` loop?

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS yes, I know but the problem is wherever I put } does not work.

Comment: @sara You are probably missing it after your for loop to close the DES method. Problem is that you also seem to be missing a return statement for that method.

Comment: You need to learn to understand where and how code blocks start and end.

Comment: always format your code neatly. if you're using eclipse use ctrl+shift+f to format source and identify brace error.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put one `}` before you begin the `public static String encrypt(String dot, SecretKey secretKey)` method, i.e. after your for-loop ends

Comment: What are those @sara?

Comment: @mohdshoaib There's 2 I can spot: Missing return statement of the Method DES and not catching the exception when calling encrypt.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS , Good Catch. I overlooked it.  This should fix the problem

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS could you please re-format the code, as I am beginner at Java

Comment: @mohdshoaib could you please re-format the code, as I am beginner at Java

Comment: @sara to prove the point, you can try this:
Add `throws Exception` after `DES( @Name("set1") List<String> strings1)` and before you begin the `public static String encrypt(String dot, SecretKey secretKey)` add 
`return null }`

Comment: @sara Due to limitations in the number of words I can write in a comment, please try below changes :
    change `public byte[] DES( @Name("set1") List<String> strings1)` ->  `public byte[] DES( @Name("set1") List<String> strings1) throws Exception`

After the line `System.out.println("Encrypted Text After Encryption: " + encryptedText);` add  `return encryptedText.getBytes();}` .

Comment: @mohdshoaib  I have done, and got this error: This method (DES) return a result of type byte [ ].

Comment: @sara did you added the line `return encryptedText.getBytes();` after the line `System.out.println("Encrypted Text After Encryption: " + encryptedText);` that is after line number 22 in the code?

Answer (score 1):

I can see that is missing a `}` to close the class `Join`, always try format the code to see this problems.

The result code is:

```
public class Join {
  static Cipher cipher;
  @UserFunction
  @Description("example.DES ,, Decryption of any input values.")
  public byte[] DES(@Name("set1") List < String > strings1) {
    for (int i = 0; i < strings1.size(); i++) {
      String dot;
      dot = strings1.get(i);
      KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
      keyGenerator.init(128);
      SecretKey secretKey = keyGenerator.generateKey();
      cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
      String encryptedText = encrypt(dot, secretKey);
      System.out.println("Encrypted Text After Encryption: " + encryptedText);
    }
  }
  public static String encrypt(String dot, SecretKey secretKey) throws Exception {
    byte[] plainTextByte = dot.getBytes();
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
    byte[] encryptedByte = cipher.doFinal(plainTextByte);
    Base64.Encoder encoder = Base64.getEncoder();
    String encryptedText = encoder.encodeToString(encryptedByte);
    return encryptedText;
  }
}
```

Comment: This leads to another error : The method encrypt(String, SecretKey) is undefined for the type Join

Comment: Sorry, but the } is before encrypt method, try it

Answer (score 1):

You have to put one `{` before encrypt method to end the for loop, like this:

```
public class Join {
  static Cipher cipher;
  @UserFunction
  @Description("example.DES ,, Decryption of any input values.")
  public byte[] DES(@Name("set1") List < String > strings1) {
    for (int i = 0; i < strings1.size(); i++) {
      String dot;
      dot = strings1.get(i);
      KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
      keyGenerator.init(128);
      SecretKey secretKey = keyGenerator.generateKey();
      cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
      String encryptedText = encrypt(dot, secretKey);
      System.out.println("Encrypted Text After Encryption: " + encryptedText);
    }
  }
  public static String encrypt(String dot, SecretKey secretKey)
  throws Exception {
    byte[] plainTextByte = dot.getBytes();
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
    byte[] encryptedByte = cipher.doFinal(plainTextByte);
    Base64.Encoder encoder = Base64.getEncoder();
    String encryptedText = encoder.encodeToString(encryptedByte);
    return encryptedText;
  }
}
```